# Not able to run PhantomJS UI test through remote selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, phantomjs, remotewebdriver

I am trying to use phantomJS through remote webdriver for UI testing. Here are the steps I have followed:

**Phantom JS:**

I have downloaded windows version from here because of an issue:
https://github.com/mrorgues/PhantomJSCustomEdition/tree/builds

**Selenium Hub:**

```
java -jar  selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub
```

**Phantom JS Node:**

```
phantomjs --webdriver=7777 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444
```

When I am trying to access the hub through the URL I see this which is good:

[image]

This is how I am initializing driver for running my tests:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
String urlString = "http://HubHostName:4444/wd/hub";
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
```

I have also tried this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("browserName","phantomjs");
String urlString = "http://HubHostName:4444/wd/hub";
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(urlString), capabilities);
```

But I am always getting the below error:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /wd/hub/session. Reason:
    <pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request: {
      &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
      },
      &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
      &quot;capabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
        &quot;alwaysMatch&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;firstMatch&quot;: []
      }
    }
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:138)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request: {
      &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
      },
      &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
      &quot;capabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
        &quot;alwaysMatch&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;firstMatch&quot;: []
      }
    }
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.extractDesiredCapability(WebDriverRequest.java:76)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.&lt;init&gt;(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:102)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.&lt;init&gt;(WebDriverRequest.java:36)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequestFactory.createFromRequest(WebDriverRequestFactory.java:30)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.createFromRequest(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:73)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:83)
     ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: First match w3c capabilities is zero length
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:164)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.&lt;init&gt;(NewSessionPayload.java:149)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:104)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.extractDesiredCapability(WebDriverRequest.java:66)
     ... 37 more
    </pre>
    <h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request: {
      &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
      },
      &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
      &quot;capabilities&quot;: {
        &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;requiredCapabilities&quot;: {},
        &quot;alwaysMatch&quot;: {
          &quot;browserName&quot;: &quot;phantomjs&quot;
        },
        &quot;firstMatch&quot;: []
      }
    }
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.extractDesiredCapability(WebDriverRequest.java:76)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.&lt;init&gt;(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:102)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.&lt;init&gt;(WebDriverRequest.java:36)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequestFactory.createFromRequest(WebDriverRequestFactory.java:30)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.createFromRequest(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:73)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:83)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: First match w3c capabilities is zero length
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:164)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.&lt;init&gt;(NewSessionPayload.java:149)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:104)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.extractDesiredCapability(WebDriverRequest.java:66)
     ... 37 more
    </pre>
    <h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: First match w3c capabilities is zero length
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.validate(NewSessionPayload.java:164)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.&lt;init&gt;(NewSessionPayload.java:149)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload.create(NewSessionPayload.java:104)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.extractDesiredCapability(WebDriverRequest.java:66)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.&lt;init&gt;(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:102)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequest.&lt;init&gt;(WebDriverRequest.java:36)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.WebDriverRequestFactory.createFromRequest(WebDriverRequestFactory.java:30)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.SeleniumBasedRequest.createFromRequest(SeleniumBasedRequest.java:73)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:83)
     at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:69)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    </pre>
    <hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.8.v20180619</a><hr/>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `String urlString = "http://ipv4_address:4444/wd/hub";`

Comment: With the same address, the selenium-webdriver is working fine. But phantomjs is not.